# How to use the gcloud storage.download attribute

Tags: python, gcloud

So basically im trying make a program in which i can upload and download files from my local to firebase storage. The following is the code used:

```
path_on_cloud = "test/test"
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()
path_local = "code.py"
storage.child(path_on_cloud).put(path_local)

storage.child(path_on_cloud).download('python_file.py')
```

but im getting an error of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Parth/Python/udfirebase.py", line 26, in <module>
    storage.child(path_on_cloud).download('img.jpg')
TypeError: download() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
```

Can someone tell what went wrong and how to solve this error

Comment: See: https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

Posting  as Community Wiki, as part of it is based in a comment.

The error you are seeing it's saying that you don't are still missing one argument in the method `download()` and this argument it's `filename`. Usually the download is made using a Blob - as the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples) indicates - ann in both situations, with Blob or not using Blob, which is your case, you will need to add the `filename` to the `download` method. You will always need to send the path and the name of the file you want to download.

Considering that, I would recommend you to give it a try changing the way you are calling your method and add the `filename`, while also including the `path`, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4/issues/7), so you avoid the error.